# Auto register classes with unity

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container

I am using Unity for dependency injection. I have bunch of classes that ends with text "Mapper" eg.

`HomeMapper`, `ContactMapper`, `EmployeeMapper`

currently im registering these classes with Unity as

```
conatiner.RegisterType<HomeMapper>;
conatiner.RegisterType<ContactMapper>;
conatiner.RegisterType<EmployeeMapper>;
```

i would like to use Unity's auto registration feature to register all classes that ends with "Mapper" and that are in certain assembly.

I have already added reference to `Unity.AutoRegistration.dll' assembly but im looking for syntax?

**Update 1**

```
public class HomeMapper
{
     private readonly MyService _service;
     public HomeMapper(MyService service)
     {
        _service = service;   
     }

     public MyModel Map(MyEntity entity)
     {
         // do mapping here
     }
}
```

Can i register `HomeMapper` as Singleton? Note it takes `MyService` instance as constructor parameter and `MyService` is register as

```
 container.RegisterType<MyService, MyService>();
```

Comment: Do you need to register _concrete_ types with [Unity](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity/)?

Comment: yes, these are concrete types, they are not derived from any interfaces

Comment: I mean you could just resolve them _without_ registering in advance. Why do you try to register these classes?

Comment: so if i have MVC controller constructor that takes one of these classes as a parameter, lets say `HomeMapper`. How would controller instance will get resolve if i have not register dependent mapper class

Answer (score 2):

With Unity you [do not need to register](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463(v=pandp.30).aspx#sec3) *concrete* classes (unlike new ASP.NET Core Dependency Injection framework where all [registrations need to be explicit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36663387/4207332)). The following test successfully creates an instance of the `HomeController` that receives `HomeMapper` as a dependency:

```
public class ResolveControllerTest
{
    [Xunit.Fact]
    public void ResolveHomeControllerWithoutRegistration()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        var controller = container.Resolve<HomeContoller>();
        Assert.NotNull(controller); // pass
    }
}

public class HomeContoller
{
    public HomeContoller(HomeMapper mapper)
    {
    }
}

public class HomeMapper
{
}
```

You *might* want to register concrete classes, for instance, when you need to customize lifetime.

**EDIT:**

Assuming that the mappers are *stateless*, all the classes that ends with "Mapper" can be registered as Singletones:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterTypes(
    AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies()
        .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Mapper")),
    WithMappings.None,
    WithName.Default,
    WithLifetime.ContainerControlled);

// controllers are 'transient' - new instance per resolve
var controller1 = container.Resolve<HomeContoller>();
var controller2 = container.Resolve<HomeContoller>();

// mapper is a singleton. Same instance returned
var mapper1 = container.Resolve<HomeMapper>();
var mapper2 = container.Resolve<HomeMapper>();
```

Comment: If i dont register concrete class then what is the defauly life time of that class. Is it per request one instance get created?

Comment: [Transient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463(v=pandp.30).aspx#sec34)

Comment: Yes they are stateless classes..Each mapper class has methods which does mapping from EF entities to model and model back to entities

Comment: So if i make mapper singleton and if mapper's contructor has a parameter which is not singleton, will it be okay? See my update 1

Comment: This parameter will _become_ a singleton. This effect is called Captive Dependency and considered as an [anti-pattern](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/issues/475#issuecomment-273911044).